# Can an App have root privileges in Android??

Tags: android

I need to write to a file and store it in /data or /system folder. The following way works

1. adb remount
2. adb shell -> chmod 777 /data , chmod 777 /system

Then my app can create files under these folders. Is there any other way to do this?? None of the permissions seem to work in this case and signing the app with the platform keys does not provide the app with root privilege as well.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions required to write:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Q : Can I change write access for root directory
A : Not by default. The root filesystem shipped on official Android devices is read-only, and only certain well-constrained areas are writable by applications.

But read this article and try :

http://www.pocketmagic.net/2009/05/write-on-the-android-read-only-file-system/#.UTErDzA9Gqs